# Arrays in at&t assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm working on an assignment to write a simpler version of sprintf, and I need to iterate through the char* to find the '%' char, which indicates where the formatting should take place. I see lots of examples around on how to do this in Intel assembly, but I'm having a hard time translating it to AT&T and applying it to my program...

```
find_index:
  cmpb $0, (%edx, %ecx, 1)      #check if end of string
  je reslength                  #go to next part of the code if true

  cmpb $'%', (%edx, %ecx, 1)    #check if byte = %
  incl %ecx                     #increase counter
  jne find_index                #if not %, check next char
```

Comment: The problem is that you clobbered the flags of `cmpb $'%', (%edx, %ecx, 1)` with `incl %ecx`. A quick and dirty fix might be to increment _ECX_ before you compare with `$` and then change the compare to `cmpb $'%', -1(%edx, %ecx, 1)` . The other option is to increment _ECX_ by 1 without modifying the flags. You can do that too by replacing `incl %ecx` with `lea 1(%ecx), %ecx` . That LEA effectively takes the value in _ECX_ adds 1 to it and stores the result in _ECX_. LEA can be used for simple arithmetic without the side effect of modifying the flags.

Comment: That worked, thank you!